# Google Cast v3 Mini Controller floats to top when used in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, google-cast

I am updating my app to use the new Google Cast v3. Looking at the Code Lab, I have set to MiniController fragment in my layout, which is a CoordinatorLayout.

MiniController Fragment:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/castMiniController"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment" />
```

Note that it is set to align to the parent bottom, however, it is up at the top of the window. See the attached screenshot.

Layout XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:contentDescription="@string/backdrop_content_description" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/castMiniController"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/outer_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/outer_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/outer_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/outer_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    style="@style/FabStyle"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like if you wrap the coordinator layout in a relative layout, then include the minicontroller after the coordinator layout, then it will be positioned appropriately at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Check my answer, it's proper way to do achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

In coordinator layout, you can not use `layout_alignParentBottom`.

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

You should change :

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

with

```
android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Relative Layout or similar ones, use
android:layout_gravity="bottom"